# Error of alert in javascript. Problem to show a string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem: when i run the program it doesn't show the alert. Maybe because i can't declare in output the string in the right way?With the alert i can show a number but how can i do it with a text?

```
<head>
<title>Triangolo rettangolo Javascript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Cifra()
{
  var t= new String(invia.testo.value);
  c=eval(invia.chiave.value);
  len=testo.length();
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        t_cifrato+=testo[i]+chiave;
          if(t_cifrato[i]>'Z')
            t_cifrato[i]=('A'-1)+(t_cifrato[i]-'Z');

    }

  alert(" Testo cifrato"+t_cifrato+);     
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="align:center">Crittografia Giulio Cesare</h1>
<form name="invia">
Inserisci testo da crittografare in maiuscolo e senza spazi:  
<input type="text" name="testo"> 
<br /><br />
Inserisci la chiave di crittografia:
<input type="text" name="chiave">
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Cifra" onclick="Cifra()">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<output type="text" value="Area">
<output type="text" value="Perimetro">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the program in C++. It works but i have a problem to translate it into the javascript one. Where is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    int chiave;
    int len;
    string testo;
    string t_cifrato;


    cout<<"Inserisci testo da crittografare in maiuscolo e senza spazi: ";
    cin>>testo;

    cout<<"Inserisci la chiave di crittografia: ";
    cin>>chiave;
    len=testo.length();
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        t_cifrato+=testo[i]+chiave;
          if(t_cifrato[i]>'Z')
            t_cifrato[i]=('A'-1)+(t_cifrato[i]-'Z');

    }

    cout<<"Testo cifrato:"<<t_cifrato;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are you trying to accomplish with your code? A bit of context might make it easier for others to provide solutions.

Comment: I have a problem to give in output the string

Comment: `alert(" Testo cifrato"+t_cifrato+);` <= you have a trailing `+` sign that should be removed

Comment: Hi, the first thing you should always try is to check for error messages in the devtools console. Press F12 and check the console tab in your browser. It would probably tell you about the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To Understand the code i have translated it into english, There are some bugs like declarations, using it without initializing like **len=testo.length();** and some HTML tags problems are also been there. So i have fixed your code as shown in snippet.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Triangolo rettangolo Javascript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Figure()
    {
      var t = new String(send.text.value);
      var c = eval(send.key.value);
  
      var len = t.length;
      var t_encrypted = "";
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            t_encrypted+=t[i]+c;
            
       if(t_encrypted[i] > 'Z')
           t_encrypted[i] = t_encrypted[i] + ('A'.charCodeAt(0) -1) +(t_encrypted[i].charCodeAt(0) -'Z'.charCodeAt(0));
        }

      alert(" Testo encrypted" + t_encrypted);     
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 style="align:center">Encryption Julius Caesar</h1>
    <form name="send">
    Enter text to be encrypted in upper case and without spaces:  
    <input type="text" name="text"> 
    <br /><br />
    Enter the encryption key:
    <input type="text" name="key"/>
    <br /><br />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Figure" onclick="Figure()"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    <output type="text" value="Area"/>
    <output type="text" value="Perimeter"/>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please do ping me up, if you need more help. Have a good day